# Opencv HoughCircles missing obvious circle

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have tried some variations in the parameters, read a [detailed description](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22648/in-opecv-function-hough-circles-how-does-parameter-1-and-2-affect-circle-detecti) of their meaning, but I can't seem to detect a simple circle in an image.  This is a simplified function I have tried:

```py
def get_a_circles(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, # input grayscale image
                              cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
                              2, 
                              minDist=5, 
                              param1=10, param2=200,
                              minRadius=0, 
                               maxRadius=0) 
    return circles
```

which, when run on this image:

```
img = cv2.imread("step2.jpg")
get_a_circle(img.copy())
```

[image]

returns none.
It does however detect the circles in this image:

| image | circles found & highlighted |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I tried to add some blur to the image that fails, with either
`gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)` or `gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)` but it does not improve the results.

Any suggestions on what to try with that image? (It would seem it's an obvious circle)

Comment: Not being familiar with the specific function, I would guess you have too few votes (looking at the link you provided - controlled by param2). Did you try reducing param2?

Comment: It requires a grayscale image (1 channel). Is the image 1 channel or 3 channels? How did you load the image?

Comment: @YuriFeldman, I had reduced it, but I guess not low enough.  `param1=20, param2=18,` does the trick, as long as I bring false positives under control with a smaller maxRadius. Thank you

Comment: @fmw42, that is a good suggestion, but the other image (generated the same way) doesn't fail (images come from a 2D numpy array `amat` and loaded as `imgint = np.interp(amat, (amat.min(), amat.max()), (0, 255)).astype('uint8')` followed by `gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgint, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`.  Could that have an influence?

Comment: If both are converted to grayscale, then that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lower param2 in HoughCircles in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('dot.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# median filter
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

# get Hough circles
min_dist = int(ww/20)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=150, param2=10, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
print(circles)

# draw circles
result = img.copy()
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
    # corresponding to the center of the circle
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    cv2.circle(result, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('dot_circle.jpg', result)

# show images
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]